# Error getting IP address: Something went wrong running an SSH command! command

Tags: ssh, docker, boot2docker

While Starting docker terminal below error populating, how to fix this 
Error getting IP address: Something went wrong running an SSH command!

```
command : ip addr show dev eth1
err     : exit status 255
output  :
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The only "solution" I've found so far is to remove the machine, and create a new one.

Comment: Is this on Windows, OSX or both?  I am seeing this on Windows 8.1